# Ubuntu 18.04 update stuck at "Setting up redis-server (5:4.0.9-1ubuntu0.1) ..."

Tags: xubuntu, redis

Whenever I update my Ubuntu software or run the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, it gets stuck at the line `Setting up redis-server (5:4.0.9-1ubuntu0.1) ...`. I don't know why this is happening.

[image: Update Manager screenshot]

Comment: I'm using 18.04

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled redis-server:

```
sudo apt-get purge redis-server
```

and installed it again from this repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/redis-server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install redis-server
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I did `ps aux`and found that redis server was working...

```
redis      535  0.0  0.1  51444  4772 ?        Ssl  01:41   0:00 /usr/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

Killed this process and it doesn't stuck again. However, still cannot install redis

```
Job for redis-server.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.################################################################################################################..................................................................................] 
See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: I did it! 
`sudo sed -i "s/bind .*/bind 127.0.0.1/g" /etc/redis/redis.conf`
`sudo service redis-server restart`

this was the problem, It couldn't run on that address and this command solved it.

Check if this is running correctly after:
`sudo tail /var/log/redis/redis-server.log`

Answer (score 1):

Systemd and redis-sentinal disagreed on where the pid file was. My /etc/redis/sentinel.conf was listing the pid as /var/run/redis/redis-sentinel.pid, whereas systemd was looking for /var/run/sentinel/redis-sentinel.pid.

As a result, systemd was killing redis-sentinel and restarting it over and over.

I updated the sentinel.conf to point to the location configured in systemd.

Comment: This was my problem too. Happened during an apt upgrade on Ubuntu 16.04. I actually changed the systemd config file to point to the same file in the redis sentinel config file. The paths to the config files are on my system: `/lib/systemd/system/redis-sentinel.service` and `/etc/redis/sentinel.conf`. I updated the `PIDFile` param in the systemd config file to have the same path as the `pidfile` in the redis sentinel config file.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem so I remove

```
rm -rf /run/systemd/generator.late/redis-server.service
```

Now it's working fine. Maybe this will help you